# angular 2 service to communicate between child and parent not working?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have bootstrap modal in which i am saving some data and after saving it i want to make that data selected in a textbox. Modal is in child component and to load that i have mentioned it in entryComponents of app module.

Now for communication in such cased i have added service will manage communication between Components.

Here my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class EmitterService {
  private events = new Subject();
  private eventSetSource = new Subject<any>();
  private eventCompletedSource = new Subject<any>();


  // Observable string streams
  eventSet$ = this.eventSetSource.asObservable();
  eventCompleted$ = this.eventCompletedSource.asObservable();

  // Service message commands
  set(obj: any) {
    this.eventSetSource.next(obj);
  }    
}
```

Here is Modal /child Component:

```
 import { EmitterService } from 'app/shared-services/emitter/emitter.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-short-organization',
      templateUrl: './short-organization.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./short-organization.component.css'],
      providers: [SessionService, ContactOrganizationService, ToastService, EmitterService]
    })
    export class ShortOrganizationComponent extends DialogComponent<ConfirmModel, boolean> implements ConfirmModel, OnInit {

      title: string;
      message: string;
      public _formGrp: FormGroup;

      constructor(dialogService: DialogService,
        private _emitterService: EmitterService
      ) {
        super(dialogService);
        _emitterService.eventCompleted$.subscribe(x => {
          console.log(x);
        })
      }

      ngOnInit() {   
      }


      onSubmit() { 
        let _userDetail = this.sessionService.getCurrentUser();
        var obj = { id: 0, value: 'xyz'};
        this._emitterService.set(obj);            
      }
```

Parent Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit,OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { ShortOrganizationComponent } from 'app/modules/manage-organization/short-organization/short-organization.component';
import { EmitterService } from 'app/shared-services/emitter/emitter.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css'],
  providers: [ 
    EmitterService
  ]
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {

  private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(  
    private _emitterService: EmitterService
  ) {
    debugger
    this._modalSubs = _emitterService.eventSet$.subscribe(
      x => {
        debugger;
        console.log(x);
        this.onSaveSelect(x);
      },
      error=>{
        debugger;
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
onSaveSelect(val) {
    debugger        
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }
}

}
```

Here i am calling this child component with dailog service using [ng2-bootstrap-modal](https://github.com/ankosoftware/ng2-bootstrap-modal) :

```
openOrganizationModal() {
    let disposable = this._dialogService.addDialog(ShortOrganizationComponent, {
      title: 'Confirm title',
      message: 'Confirm message'
    }, { backdropColor: 'rgba(23, 19, 19, 0.5)' })
      .subscribe((x) => {
        console.log(x)
      });   
  }
```

This code is loading my child component in my parent component and this method is called on some button click.

On set of value my subscribed code in parent is not getting called. Is anything missing here?
**** i have copied it from application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provide `EmitterService` **only** on the parent component (or in `@NgModule()`), otherwise each component will get its own instance which makes communication impossible, because one component is listening on a different instance than what the other is using to send the event.

Comment: Ok. I think mentioning it in parent will be better as in second case where it is added in @NgModule  will make it create single instance for all parent child(if i use it as common service for communication) and in that case value set but say child1 for parent1 will be available for parent2. Am i right? or i am thinking like a noob.

Comment: Keeping EmitterService in @NgModule worked but keeping it in only Parent did not worked. As i mentioned before i am loading child component using entryComponents is it not working because of it? I am not sure here

Comment: Not sure what you mean with `entryComponents`, do you create it with `viewContainerRef.createComponent()`. I would need to see more details to be able to tell what's going on. If the component is not actually a child component of the one that has the service in `providers: [...]`, then it can't work, how it's added as child shouldn't matter.

Comment: I doubt the component will be added as a child component if dialogService is used. Check the DOM when the component is visible if it is inside the parent component. I'd rather expect it to be added directly as child of `AppComponent` or even as sibling of `AppComponent`.

Comment: yeah you are right it's a sibling of my main component and direct child of app-root. now what should i do?

Comment: I think the only way is to provide the service in `@NgModule() class AppModule{}`